# Ambiguous definition/notation for functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus, definition

I thought the definition and notation for a function was $f(x)$ or $f(x,y)$ and so on for a multivariable function. 
However I have also seen this definition $$f(x,y,y')$$ which I think in explicit form is$f(x,y(x),y'(x))$, i.e. $y$ is a function of $x$. Is it correct? 
[You can see an exemple here (first equation)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html).

So if I'm given a function, say $f(x,y)=y+2x$, how do I know we don't actually mean $f(x,y(x))=y(x)+2x$?

Have I missed something or why this ambiguous definition/notation?

Comment: I would assume that definition is unique to differential equations.

Comment: I don't think there is an ambiguity here. $f$ itself is a function of three arguments, and you can take any three related values $a$, $b$, and $c$ and evaluate $f(a,b,c)$. To define a differential equation, you are asked to imagine a separate function $y$ of a single argument, and plug its value and derivative at a particular point $x$ into $f$ to obtain a new function of $x$, let's call it $g(x) = f(x, y(x), y'(x))$. Now if we referred to that function of $x$ also as $f(x)$, then there would be an ambiguity.

Comment: Yeah along with what Rahul said, I don't think there is an apriori reason to believe there should be an implicate relation between any of the variables unless otherwise specified

Comment: Context. Context. Context. In most cases we can say that $f(x,y(x),y'(x)) = f(x,y,y') = f(x,y)$ (the derivative is calculated from $y$ and is thus not a free variable, and can thus be implicit). It really depends on *historical precedence*, which is *clearest*and *easiest* to understand, and what *context* the notation show up in.

Comment: Whoops, that should have been "any three *unrelated* values $a$, $b$, and $c$" in my comment.